# Check if MySQL server is installed

Tags: mysql, nsis

```
IfFileExists "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server *" MySQLInstalled 0
messageBox MB_OK "Please install MySQL Server to continue!"
Quit

MySQLInstalled:
"code..."
```

I want to check if mysql server is installed, what do i miss here?

Comment: This code is horrible, what if MySQL is installed somewhere else or program files is not on c:\? Please read about $programfiles in the NSIS docs...

Answer (score 1):

Try using Registry Checks to determine if MYSQL is installed. I have proved that this works.

```
    ClearErrors
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MYSQL "ImagePath"
${If} ${Errors}
  MessageBox MB_OK "Value not found [$0]"
${Else}  
    MESSAGEBOX MB_OK "UgandaEMRTomcat is installed at $0 do you want to proceed"
${EndIf}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about checking registry key?

Almost all software uses registry to keep information about installation location.

Usually if key exists there is ''Install path'', ''Install Location'' of similar value available.